JavaScript, dynamically decode C style string escape characters E.G. the escape decode part of snprintf()
Based on some user input fields on a webpage, a string primitive is created that contains some C-style escape sequences.  E.G. \n \t etc.
What is the proper, safe, way of decoding such a string?  In most other languages that I've used for text processing the string format function can be used for this task; not just replacing magic variables.  While it would also be nice if I could pass a map/dictionary/key-value object to the format specification and have it replace those too, it's possible to work backwards with .replace and manually replace the values.
I'd rather not also re-invent the wheel for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#escape_sequences and ideally all the other supported string Character Escapes could also be decoded https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Character_escape
EDIT 2024-06-05: I've updated the code section for added clarity.
"use strict";
// oversimplified JS function example
function someButtonClicked() {
  // End user types a line such as \n\tLine Two, with a tab\nLine Three
  var userInput = document.getElementsByName("TextBox")[0].value;
  // Equivalently...
  var userInput = "\\n\\tLine Two, with a tab\\nLine Three";
  // DESIRED RESULT: dynamically evaluate the escapes as entered into REAL characters
  var parsed = "";

  // Is there no way to reach this result other than eval() ?
  var DesiredResult = "\n\tLine Two, with a tab\nLine Three";
  // The above escapes are parsed to real characters
  // during initial script parse for a multi line result string.

  // I want to do the equivalent of this C style code
  // char parsed[strlen(userInput)] ; snprintf(parsed, strlen(userInput), userInput)
  // NOW parsed = "\n\tLine Two, with a tab\nLine Three"
  // Note: escaped characters decoded to real characters

  // parsed must be set within the function context, not global context...
  // After much searching and trial and error, all I've found is eval :(
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval
  eval("parsed = `" + userInput + "`")

  console.log("Desired Result, 3 lines:\n", DesiredResult, "\n\neval() result, 3 lines:\n", parsed, "\n\n", DesiredResult === parsed);
}

Surely, there has to be a better way than using eval?  However my efforts to use a search engine are greatly hampered by the poorly named 'unescape' (Really decodeURIComponent) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Is there an actual problem to solve? If a user inputs the two character \ and n then the value of userInput will have the sequence of \ and n, and not a newline. The sequence \n only works in string literals. Which means in the source code. If you're taking the value from a user input that's not source code. Demo

OK, I think I misread. You don't want to remove newlines. You want to add newlines. In which case, eval "works". The local/global context thing is not an issue because you don't have to assign to a variable in eval just do foo = eval(bar) which returns the result. However, that exposes you to problems like if the user types in while(true) as their input. So, you can interpret escape sequences but also any other code. IMO, if you have user input you just let them use actual newlines and tabs, etc. Not escape sequences. https://jsbin.com/moduzotunu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

You've misunderstood.  The source data might contain multiple lines but contains 'escaped' slashes already.  Just like I stated, assume userInput contains: "\n\tLine Two, with a tab\nLine Three" << With the double slashes.  Which should turn INTO three lines of output, one of which also has a tab, and one of which is blank.

I updated the source example to better explain things.  The END USER types in e.g \n or any other Escapee Sequence, Is there no way of decoding that other than eval()?  Isn't there some safe string processing function to do this task?

Why not use Replace?

"Isn't there some safe string processing function to do this task?" not any that is built-in. There are libraries that would do it. However, I think in many cases it is a search and replace with a known list of symbols/combinations. In general, I'd avoid doing that as much as possible, instead expecting the data to come in without anything that needs processing. But if it has to be done, then define a known way to process the data. Using something that "just works" is a recipe to...not work. Either it does more or maybe less than what you want. And is tightly bound to the tech, too.

The functionality I desire already exists, since every interpreter performs it at parse.  It's crazy to me that there's no better / safer method of decoding a string than eval().

It's too bad VLAZ didn't submit that AS an answer... It's not really a 'solution' but it is the current correct answer as far as I know.  There is NOT a good way of doing this.
